# Can't push or commit to GitHub in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, github, git-commit

1. I created Git Hub account and clone using SSH

   [image: GitHub]
2. I went to Create Git Repositories. I chose both project folders POD and SFITNESS. Then xCode created the following:

   [image: The following]
3. Then I right click on SFITNESS and ADD EXISTING REMOTE which I log in to GitHub to provide the link, everything works fine.
4. When I went to commit, I choose the SFTNESS folder and commit and at the bottom it allows me to Push to remote which I choose the remote at step 3.
5. Then it will prompt me for the Username and Password and I can never get the authentication correct. The Username and password is it for Github? I can never get the authentication correct?

   [image: Pic 3]

   [image: Pic 4]
6. Now, at the commit window I have lost my SFITNESS folder, how do I commit again? Is it push now?

   [image: Pic 5]

Comment: You should try ssh key, not username and password, on login method and choose the 2nd one

Comment: Generate ssh key at GitHub page and also now is it push, I can't commit anymore?

Comment: open keychain Access and  search github if exist delete then try again all steps  to push repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to Add SSH following this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) and use SSH as authenthication.