# Xcode 10 github push broken?

Tags: github, xcode10

Using Xcode 10 (not beta) and a paid GitHub account. I can't push a git update through Xcode to my account, from multiple different boxes - anyone else having an issue with Xcode pushes to GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

If depends on the URL used, and if it was working before today (considering the recent GitHub outage)

For instance, if you are using an HTTPS URL, try and switch to an SSH one, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748849/6309).
Check also if the same push would work from command line, [as tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48795062/6309).

As the [OP Nostradamus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961425/nostradamus) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977665/xcode-10-github-push-broken/52981811?noredirect=1#comment92898342_52981811), XCode9 does not have this issue.

Comment: thanks appreciate the response - I've sent a note to their tech support to confirm it's not something their end.

Comment: I've gone back to using Xcode 9 and all is well again. (plus I don't have to deal with a floating object library window, the last word in poor UX/UI)

Comment: @Nostradamus Good move. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.